# Finding within-groups specific sequences

Tags: r, sequences

I am working on a data set including the results of repeated tests (results expressed as positive(1)/negative(0)) on individuals over time; the number of tests per individual is not necessarily the same.
below is a df reproducing how my dataset looks like:

```
id<-c(rep("a", time=5), rep("b", time=5), rep("c",time=7))
date<-as.Date(c("2018-03-01","2018-04-01","2018-06-01","2018-08-01","2018-10-01","2017-03-01","2017-04-01","2018-02-01","2018-11-01","2018-12-01","2016-05-11","2017-10-01","2018-03-01","2018-03-21","2018-4-01","2018-07-01","2018-08-01"))
test<-c(1,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0)
df<-data.frame(id, test, date)
df
id test       date
a    1 2018-03-01
a    1 2018-04-01
a    0 2018-06-01
a    1 2018-08-01
a    0 2018-10-01
b    0 2017-03-01
b    1 2017-04-01
b    0 2018-02-01
b    1 2018-11-01
b    1 2018-12-01
c    0 2016-05-11
c    0 2017-10-01
c    1 2018-03-01
c    0 2018-03-21
c    0 2018-04-01
c    1 2018-07-01
c    0 2018-08-01
```

what I am trying to do is to create a new column 'Var' indicating whether any of the following set of results:

```
match1<-c(1,1,1,1)
match2<-c(1,1,1,0)
match3<-c(0,1,1,1)
match4<-c(1,0,1,1)
match5<-c(1,1,0,1)
```

is observed in the result set of each individual. ideally this would result in:

```
id test       date      Var
a    1 2018-03-01     case
a    1 2018-04-01     case
a    0 2018-06-01     case
a    1 2018-08-01     case
a    0 2018-10-01     case
b    0 2017-03-01     case
b    1 2017-04-01     case
b    0 2018-02-01     case
b    1 2018-11-01     case
b    1 2018-12-01     case
c    0 2016-05-11 non-case
c    0 2017-10-01 non-case
c    1 2018-03-01 non-case
c    0 2018-03-21 non-case
c    0 2018-04-01 non-case
c    1 2018-07-01 non-case
c    0 2018-08-01 non-case
```

because the sequence (1,1,0,1) is observed within the result set of 'a', (1,0,1,1) in 'b' while none of the target sequences is observed in 'c'.

Apologize for not posting any attempt but I am really stuck with this!
best regards,
Matteo

Comment: `l <- mget(ls(pattern = 'match\\d')); df$Var <- c('non-case', 'case')[with(df, ave(test, id, FUN = function(x) any(sapply(l, function(m) grepl(toString(m), toString(x)))))) + 1L]`

Comment: that's very smart thank you very much rawr!